# Want Internet Explorer does not show top menu while hovering with the mouse

Tags: mouse, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I use IE in fullscreen mode and I use some sort of website with virtual machines with the internet explorer.

The problem is, when I want to close a window in VM, I move the mouse on the top right of the screen to press the X button, I accidentally close the internet explorer. Because of that, I really need a way to hide the top menu.

I am sure this problem should be common for others so I hope this question can help them as well.

I have IE 11, Windows 10 OS.

[image: I want to get ride of the top menu (shown with the red drawn shape]

Comment: By VM do you mean Vmware or Virtualbox?
According to Microsoft, this is the only option.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/desktop-ie11-hide-top-title-bar-possible/8a1d7967-3ce6-415d-a3e6-9f79fdd09717

Comment: by VM I mean a special website that allows virtualization of an OS. For security reasons, I can not name it. sorry :-(

Comment: about the microsft answers: they are suggesting pressing Winkey+F11 which actually blocks the top bar and does not hide it. I hope there will be a solution with registry manipulation :-)